# Digital Dead Drops or guaranteed significant uncertainty of identity over TCP/IP for a large set of users

Tags: encryption, public-key, protocol-design

Client is part of a Set members. Every distinct object in members has in common, that they do want to communicate to the Server without the Server or other objects of members knowing the origin of each individual communication.

Required is a way for Client to upload data to the Server without the Server knowing about which of the objects of members the data belongs to.

Is there any way of implementing this besides open, cascaded proxy networks, which are in general rather slow, especially for large files?

Comment: It might be reasonable to describe the problem again, as well as check "Dining cryptographers" of Chaum.